# Not opening in WebView but in browser

Tags: android, webview

I want to open the following link in WebView

https://tickets.musiconelive.com/admin/SACValidateBarcode.asp

I am using following code to do that

```
web=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.loadUrl("https://tickets.musiconelive.com/admin/SACValidateBarcode.asp");
```

but it's not opening in WebView and instead is opening in the browser.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: in my example i have update https to http.

Comment: Can some one answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49099883/why-pdf-not-opening-in-iframe-in-chrome-when-switched-to-mobile-device-mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think this will help you.

```
 package com.adySol;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
 import android.webkit.WebView;

 public class adySol extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


 String url ="http://tickets.musiconelive.com/admin/SACValidateBarcode.asp";
 WebView wv=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
 wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); 
 wv.loadUrl(url);
    }
  }
```

**Main.xml**::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
>
 <WebView android:id="@+id/webView1" android:layout_width="match_parent"  android:layout_height="match_parent"></WebView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Manifest permission** :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: i cant find the setPluginState() and PluginState.On

Comment: i have update my code please watch it and still got problem then ping me

Comment: i think you need to import some library i give to you shoutcut for it (crtl + shift + o )

Comment: i dont want to change the https to http because it effecting the action part of url

Comment: @scorpio let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1443/discussion-between-user606559-and-scorpio)

Comment: i cant able to continue in chat becase firewall problem

Comment: is there any other way to open that link without changeing the url

Comment: i dont know , this is the best way to do that. another way is web service

Comment: @NikunjPatel Can you update your answer with root cause and the exact change needed for the fix? This should help future visitors in finding the required solution more efficiently.

Answer (score 10):

may this helps you

```
        WebSettings mWebSettings;

        WebView mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.services_detail_magnified_image);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
        mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_INSET);

        mWebView.loadUrl(StaticURL.uChangePassword);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient { 
        @Override 
        //show the web page in webview but not in web browser
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) { 
            view.loadUrl (url); 
            return true;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: helloo this code is gud for only single webview.i want to add the wegview in in listview.is it posible?wanna play gif in webview..you can also see the link of my questions.

Comment: you can see the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159336/gif-not-animated-in-custom-listview

Comment: for me worked like this:
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
so there was no need to create an extra class

Answer (score 0):

You need to set  WebViewClient()

```
This is example in kotlin
webview.apply {
            loadUrl("https://www.google.com/")
            webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        }
```

As per android documentation
public void setWebViewClient (WebViewClient client)
Sets the WebViewClient that will receive various notifications and requests. This will replace the current handler.

Answer (score -1):

```
    webView=findViewById(R.id.webView);        
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR)
    webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_INSET);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(MyWebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("https://google.com/");



class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient() {
    @override
    boolean  shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view , WebResourceRequest request) {
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request)
    }
}
```

Comment: No sence in overriding