# Why PDF not opening in iFrame in Chrome when switched to Mobile Device Mode

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe, webview, uiwebview

This shows the pdf when we open it in browser.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/44678.pdf" width="100%" height="100%" >
</iframe>  
</body>
</html>
```

But when I switch it to mobile view, it DOESNT work.
Steps:

> 1. Open Chrome Inspect Window.
> 2. Click "Toggle Device Toolbar" icon  on the top menu on inspect window toolbar.
> 3. Now we can still see the pdf in mobile view.
> 4. Once we refresh it, we can NO LONGER SEE pdf.
> 5. Why ? I need to iframe the pdf and show it in mobile app in web view.
> 6. Is it possible or not ?

Comment: A WebView cannot display a pdf.

Comment: Then how to show pdf in mobile app while we are in web view ?

Comment: Install a pdf viewer app on your device.

Comment: Further Google has a service to convert a pdf document on the fly to html. Just give the service the url for the pdf.